# Why do (a lot) fewer than 95% of my confidence intervals intersect the true parameter value in this simulation?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

Why are my confidence intervals performing so poorly?

I have a data frame `may` of two variables $C$ and $F$. I perform a linear regression

```
lm.1 <- lm(may$C ~ may$F)
lm.1$coef[2]
#  may$F
#  0.0161821  
confint(lm.1)[c(2,4)]
# [1] 0.0151  0.0173
```

So far so good. I then want to simulate running a sample and getting the confidence interval from each sample, similar to [this illustration from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NYW-confidence-interval.svg). However when I do -- expecting to get 95% of my intervals to intersect the true parameter (`0.0161`) -- I find that only 55% (!!) of my intervals intersect the correct parameter.[image: 100 confidence intervals with true parameter]

```
sample.size <- 15

plot(c(1,n), c(0, 0.03), type="n")
  lines(x=c(-1,n+1), y=c(0.016,0.016), lty=2, col=2)
  x <- cbind(rep(0,n), rep(0,n))
for (i in 1:n){
  may.temp <- may
  lm.temp <- NA
  set.seed(i*3)
  may.temp <- may.temp[sample(1:nrow(may.temp), sample.size), ]
  lm.temp <- lm(may.temp$C ~ may.temp$F)

  x[i, 1] <- confint(lm.temp)[2,1]
  x[i, 2] <- confint(lm.temp)[2,2]

  lines(x=c(i,i), y=c(x[i,1], x[i,2]), col="blue", lwd=2)
}
y <- rep(0,n)
for (i in 1:n){
  if( x[i,1] < 0.017 & x[i,2] > 0.015){
  y[i] <- 1
}
}
sum(y)
# 55
```

I had two thoughts:

1. My sample size (15) is too low. But I thought the confidence intervals would simple become larger to take this into account.
2. My data has outliers. My data does have outliers, but (from my non-expert eye) these don't seem to bias the model.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: This is not actually simulation under the assumptions of regression, but bootstrapping (resampling your data). Why do you think this will have the right coverage probability?

Comment: Well, I guess there's my problem. So if I do not **re**sample my data will I get the intended result?

Comment: If you sample under the assumptions from which the coverage of the intervals is derived (and you do it correctly) then yes, you should get the desired coverage probability (up to sampling error and accumulated numerical error). That means you'll be sampling from normal distributions. It should work even for small samples. The justification for bootstrapping is asymptotic, not exact, and intervals based off normal theory won't have the right coverage at small sample sizes.